# How to execute a class member function in a separate thread using C++11 thread class?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, xcode4.6

I'm trying to use the C++11's `std::thread` class to run a member function of a class to execute in parallel.

The header file's code is similar to:

```
class SomeClass {
    vector<int> classVector;
    void threadFunction(bool arg1, bool arg2);
public:
    void otherFunction();
};
```

The cpp file is similar to:

```
void SomeClass::threadFunction(bool arg1, bool arg2) {
    //thread task
}

void SomeClass::otherFunction() {
    thread t1(&SomeClass::threadFunction, arg1, arg2, *this);
    t1.join();
}
```

I am using Xcode 4.6.1 under Mac OS X 10.8.3. The compiler I am using is Apple LLVM 4.2 which came with the Xcode.

The above code does not work. The compiler error says that `"Attempted to use deleted function"`.

On the line of thread creation it shows the following massage.

```
In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::thread::thread<void (SomeClass::*)(bool, bool), bool &, bool &, FETD2DSolver &, void>' requested here
```

I'm new in C++11 and the thread class. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The instance should be the second argument, like so:

```
std::thread t1(&SomeClass::threadFunction, *this, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: It's worth to point out that the OPs code is useless if he calls `.join()` immediatly.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if, for example, `arg2` is a reference.

Comment: @Groosha: `arg2` is an expression, and expressions are never references. However, if you would like to pass an argument *by reference*, you can wrap it in `std::ref`: `std::thread(&X::f, this, std::ref(arg))`.

Answer (score 1):

I still had problems with the above answer (I think it was complaining it could not copy over a smart pointer?), so rephrased it with a lambda:

```
void SomeClass::otherFunction() {
  thread t1([this,arg1,arg2](){ threadFunction(arg1,arg2); });
  t1.detach();
}
```

Then it compiled and ran fine. AFAIK, this is just as efficient, and personally I find it more readable.

(Note: I've also changed `join()` to `detach()` as I expect that was the intent.)